# Most efficient way to do batch INSERT IGNORE using doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a script that needs go get a list of entries in the database then iterate over those creating new entries in another table if they dont already exists.

Currently im doing:

```
foreach($entries as $entry){
    $newItem = new Item();
    $newItem->setAttribute($entry->getAttribute());
    $entityManager->persist($newItem);
    try{
        $entityManager->flush();
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        if(!strpos($e->getMessage(),'Duplicate')){
            throw $e;
        }
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
        //refreshes the entity manager
    }

}
```

However doing it this way is very time intensive, there are 1000's of entries and the script some times takes upwards of 10 minutes to complete. I have seen other posts suggest when doing batch processing like this to flush every 20 or so records the problem with that is that if one of those 20 are a duplicate then the whole transaction dies, im not sure how i would go back and try and find the offending entry to exclude it before resubmitting them again.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't `flush()` your batch inside the `foreach()` loop...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do one `SELECT` to fetch records that already exist in database, and later just skip these records. Additionally, try to execute `flush()` and `clear()` just once or play around with the batch size. I would also suggest to use transaction (if you use InnoDB).

```
$this->_em->getConnection()
    ->beginTransaction();

try {
    $created = array(/* all primary keys that already exist */);
    $i = 1;
    $batchSize = sizeof($entries);
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {

        if (in_array($entry->getMyPrimaryKey(), $created)) {
            continue;
        }

        $newItem = new Item();
        $newItem->setAttribute($entry->getAttribute());
        $entityManager->persist($newItem);

        if (($i % $batchSize) == 0) {
            $this->_em->flush();
            $this->_em->clear();
        }

        $i++;
    }

    $this->_em->getConnection()
        ->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->_em->getConnection()
        ->rollback();
    $this->_em->close();

    throw new \RuntimeException($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: The problem with doing them in all 1 transaction is that if I have 32,000 entries the transaction is HUGE and exceeds the max run time of  scripts. It also hogs all the system resources which is why i use more frequent flushes

Comment: Also why us $i in the foreach loop at all of you are just going to run the flush and clear when its done? Why not just move it to right after the foreach?

Comment: sorry, I updated the code, idea was to call `flush` only once (it worked for me), otherwise you will have to play around batch size. Although, if you have to insert `32,000`, `DBAL` might be viable solution.

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd Completely agree on use of `DBAL`. With that many records any type of `ORM` will come crumbling down :-/

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd @jperovic What would a `DBAL` approach look like?

Comment: @Chausser DBAL is basically a wrapper for PDO. Therefore, you will be able to insert data with minimum Doctrine's overhead. Read more here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html

Comment: Caution- this approach will be very ugly if the number of existing PKs is large (in my case several 100k).